# Combining Oracle xpath expressions

Tags: xpath, oracle11g

I'm running xpath on Oracle 11g.
Using the following code i'm trying to select the number element under the application element with @code="A2" or "U2". If no such @code attribute exists then I just want to select the first application element, with or without a @code attribute.
The 2 expressions (2nd one commented out) in the following code work individually for the 2 halves of the problem:

1) Where @code="A2" or "U2"

2) The first application

Can anyone please tell me how to combine these 2 expressions:

```
WITH et
AS (SELECT XMLType (
'<patent>
    <applications>
        <application code="U7">
            <applicationId>
                <number>351149</number>
            </applicationId>
         </application>
         <application>
           <applicationId>
               <number>54632</number>
           </applicationId>
         </application>
         <application code="A2">
           <applicationId>
               <number>DM090884</number>
           </applicationId>
         </application>
   </applications>
</patent>
' ) xt
  from dual
   ) 
    SELECT     
        ext.*
       FROM
       et,
       XMLTABLE('/patent'
passing et.xt
Columns
           APPLICATION_NUMBER VARCHAR (14)  
               PATH 'applications/application[(@code="A2"  or @code="U2" )][1]/applicationId/number'
             --PATH ' applications/application[1]/applicationId/number'
) ext
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the logic can be - return  `a` or return `b` if there is no `a`

```
a | b[not(../a)]
```

In your case is something as:

```
applications/
(application[(@code="A2"  or @code="U2")] |
 application[not(../application[@code="A2"  or @code="U2"])])
[1]/applicationId/number
```

I have splitted the line for readability

Comment: Works a treat, thanks. The 2 ,non interchangeable, or's (or,|) are a bit confusing but I can see how they work now.

Comment: `application[(@code="A2"  or @code="U2")]` - is `a` from the 1st example. If it's present, it will be returned, and condition `[not(../a)]` will be false. Otherwise, if there is no `a` it can't be returned, but condition is true and you get `b`.

Comment: Splash58 It's just been pointed out that your query does not work for the following xml: <patent>
<applications>
<application>
<applicationId>
<number>DM090884</number>
</applicationId>
</application>
<application code="A2">
<applicationId>
<number>351149</number>
</applicationId>
<textDescription>International Design Filing</textDescription>
</application>
</applications>
</patent>   --The 'A2' code should get selected, not the frst application

Comment: for your xml `patent/applications/(application[(@code="A2"  or @code="U2")] | application[not(../application[@code="A2"  or @code="U2"])]) [1]/applicationId/number` gets `Element='<number>DM090884</number>'`

Comment: Yes, my mistake, apologies